# onmousemove triggers only on rightclick

Tags: javascript, php, html, xampp

I have a problem with onmousemove. I've created a div element and added `onmousemove="doSomething()"` to it but it wouldn't work. Until now I have tried to do it with `addEventListener()`, `object.onmousemove=doSomething()` and I've copied the vital code from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousemove_html), where it works fine, to the end of my page.

I've discovered that both codes fire an event, which works fine - all functions are executed as they should be when the mouse moves - when I rightclick on the element with onmousemove. The same happens if i try to use event listeners.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

EDIT: I have now discovered that the real problem is, that the page loads as an action in an other pages form. (creating a file at which onmousemove works and then trying to load it with the same form) The form is uploading files - images and I'm using xampp.

Comment: *and I've copied the vital code from w3schools* Don't refer that site if you want to learn nicely

Comment: The w3schools reference is just a code that works on my Chrome. Now i've tried adding a iframe at the end of the body and removed the onload on it. Still the same - works only on rightclick. I'm using XAMPP btw, the file is .php and is shown after a form submit (post).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should assign Function but not result

```
  -> object.onmousemove=doSomething    // no brackets
```

same goes for add event listener

```
 object.addEventListener('mousemove', doSomething , false);
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Sorry. :D

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this to capture mouse move event on page

```
var xPrev = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   $(document).mousemove(function(e){
       xPrev<e.pageX ? $('#lr').html("right") : $('#lr').html("left");
       xPrev=e.pageX;
      $('#status').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);

   }); 
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/Yuk4K/)

Comment: OP never said anything about jQuery

Comment: Ok I apologize ,i had not seen the question was tagged to javascript.

Comment: Thanks, but i haven't learned jQuery jet, since i can do everything in javascript. I know it's "harder", but it doesn't matter. In javascript I have indeed tried to add the event to the document - document.addEventListener ...- or something like that. Same result.